# Azure Data Tables JS SDK - how to set Request Header - contentType: application/json;odata=nometadata

Tags: javascript, azure, datatables, request-headers

### Question: is there a way to set the request header item
contentType: application/json;odata=nometadata
prior to a call to TableClient.listEntities.
Objective: to receive data payloads uncluttered with odata metadata.

I am using the Azure Data Tables JavaScript API, and would like to specify request header item as follows:-

contentType: application/json;odata=nometadata

I've looked through the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/data-tables/?view=azure-node-latest) and there are some methods which facilitate changes to the request header, e.g. TableInsertEntityHeaders interface includes a property 'contentType'.

the TableClient.listEntities method includes a parameter (options?: ListTableEntitiesOptions) which does not include header access.  So, as far as I can see, there is no obvious functionality supplied by the API to change the Request Header.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this in `format` parameter in the query options. Please see the sample code below:

```
const { TableClient, AzureNamedKeyCredential } = require("@azure/data-tables");

const account = "account-name";
const accountKey = "account-key";
const tableName = "table-name";

const credential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential(account, accountKey);
const client = new TableClient(`https://${account}.table.core.windows.net`, tableName, credential);

async function main() {
  let entitiesIter = client.listEntities({
    queryOptions: {
      format: "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    }
  });
  let i = 1;
  for await (const entity of entitiesIter) {
    console.log(`Entity ${i}:`);
    console.log(entity);
    console.log('==================');
    i++;
  }
}

main();
```